# Why doesn't this OpenMP paralelize?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I've got this code and method here:

```
#include <omp.h>

const int TS_GLOBAL = 20;

void apply_grayscale(uint8_t* input_buffer,uint8_t* output_buffer,uint16_t image_w,uint16_t image_h)
{
size_t pixel_row_size = 3 * image_w;
if(pixel_row_size % 4)
    pixel_row_size += 4 - (pixel_row_size % 4);

    
const int TS = TS_GLOBAL;
#pragma omp taskloop grainsize(TS) // <------- here
for(uint16_t i = 0; i < image_h; i++)
    {
        uint8_t* current_input_buffer = input_buffer + (i * pixel_row_size);
        uint8_t* current_output_buffer = output_buffer + (i * pixel_row_size);
    
        grayscale_row(current_input_buffer,current_output_buffer,image_w);
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to scale too well. When doing it with

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

it has a significant increase in speed. Nevertheless, I need it to work with an OpenMP's tasks implementation too. Here is a code snippet of a working `#prama omp parallel` that works just fine.

```
void apply_grayscale(uint8_t* input_buffer,uint8_t* output_buffer,uint16_t image_w,uint16_t image_h)
{
    size_t pixel_row_size = 3 * image_w;
    if(pixel_row_size % 4)
        pixel_row_size += 4 - (pixel_row_size % 4);
    
        
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < image_h; i++)
    {
        uint8_t* current_input_buffer = input_buffer + (i * pixel_row_size);
        uint8_t* current_output_buffer = output_buffer + (i * pixel_row_size);
        
        grayscale_row(current_input_buffer,current_output_buffer,image_w);
    }
}
```

However, I want to use the task paradigm, to gain a better understanding of the technology.

I found this task parallelization from [openmp's official tutorial site](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-UMT-Tasking-1.pdf). It should do virtually the same task-oriented for.

Any idea why I don't get any gains?

Comment: What `grayscale_row` does? Is it computationally expensive? I do not see any parallel region in your code. Did you use `#pragma omp parallel` and  `#pragma omp single`? Note that OpenMP tasks has bigger overheads than `#pragma omp parallel for`, this can be a potential reason.

Comment: What do you get if you remove `grainsize(TS) `?

Comment: To quote the standard: "A taskloop region binds to the innermost enclosing parallel region". There is no parallel region in your code

Comment: @Laci grayscale_row is a method that transforms a row of colored pixels of a photo to grayscale. To visualize this, it's literally a grayscale filter, but only for a single line. 
Regarding the omp parallel and omp single I gave a deeper explication in the question text.

Comment: @Homer512 But what prevents the for from being parallelized? see (https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-UMT-Tasking-1.pdf page 24 right hand side). I did it in the same way as in the manual. From my point of view, it's the same problem as in the manual. 
The task-parallel is the for loop.

Comment: That code snippet is misleading. Use it like here: https://hpc2n.github.io/Task-based-parallelism/branch/master/task-basics-2/

Comment: You seem to have implemented the code snippet that was described as "quite complicated and easy to implement incorrectly." It seems to me that your task look was the better aproach and the only thing missing was the `omp parallel` region. In the pdf file you cite the `omp taskloop` code fragment should replace the `for` loop in the 3rd block on the left. That is: embed the `taskloop` in `omp parallel / omp single`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy to @Homer512 it's now working. If anyone ever encounters this issue again, here is how I solved it!

```
const int per_task = 2;

void apply_grayscale(uint8_t* input_buffer,uint8_t* output_buffer,uint16_t image_w,uint16_t image_h){
  size_t pixel_row_size = 3 * image_w;
  if(pixel_row_size % 4)
      pixel_row_size += 4 - (pixel_row_size % 4);

  
  #pragma omp parallel
  #pragma omp single
  {
      for(uint16_t i = 0; i < image_h; i+=per_task) {
          #pragma omp task
          {
              for (int j = 0; j < per_task && i + j < image_h; j++) {
                  uint8_t* current_input_buffer = input_buffer + ((i + j) * pixel_row_size);
                  uint8_t* current_output_buffer = output_buffer + ((i + j) * pixel_row_size);            
                  grayscale_row(current_input_buffer,current_output_buffer,image_w);
              }
          }
      }   
  }
}
}
```